# How can I recover funds recovery from coldcard?

Tags: wallet-recovery, coldcard

I recently bought a Coldcard mk4 and did some tries to understand how it works. I moved a tiny amount to test it but now I can't recover it.

What I think happened is: I exported the wallet created with the CC and imported in Blue Wallet app on my iPhone, then I used one of the addresses generated by the watch only blue wallet.

I have:

24 words mnemonics
passphrase
the addresses I used to transact those lost sats
the xpub associated to those address

my fear is having played around with derivetion paths settings I may have used some path that I don’t know or remember anymore.

Do you think is it doable to recover them starting from this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it may have to do with the path you used.

1. Check what address type you're using on BlueWallet. Usually people use bc1 addresses.
2. Re-export the wallet file to something like sparrow or electrum and the funds may show up again.
3. Here's a great sparrow tutorial video that may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAYmE5-40PQ
4. If you can't remember the path you can guess as many times as you want but you will need the correct path to access those funds. Here's our path docs: https://coldcard.com/docs/paths

Cheers,
Coinkite Team